# Spark Dataframe manipulation for statistics

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe with columns like `col1, col2, ... col40`.

I am going to create statistics out of this table,
sum(col1), min(col2), count(col20), count(how many negatives on col6).. so on.

And I need to insert each statistics as a row in a table like below,

```
"col1 summary"| sum(col1) | timestamp
"col6 negatives"| count(negative cols6) | timestamp
"min of col2"|min(col2)| timestamp
```

Please suggest a best way to do that?  Do i have to create separate dataframe for each row and union it together?

Comment: What is timestamp ? The time when you finished the calculation ?
What is the real expected output ? RDD ? DataFrame ? DataSet ?

Comment: It is Dataframe. I am creating a statistics for each input file we are processing and storing those in a table for validations. Timestamp is a just a current timestamp and we will add couple of columns with string literals. Right now my approach is, creating aggregated statistics using functions for all the required columns and manipulating each row with different string literals/timestamp.